# Alias in fish shell

Tags: linux, alias, fish

I want to update my apt and brew packages with one command by sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && brew update && echo "done updating brew" && brew upgrade && echo "done upgrading brew". I tried to put this whole command in one alias but it is showing as expected 2 arguments but got 4. Is it because i used too many? can i break down this command into 2 or 3 small commands and then merge them together.

I was expecting it to work fine because when i tried in command line it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you got the quoting wrong. That entire text is the full text of the alias, so it will need to be quoted as one argument like

```
alias update='sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && brew update && echo "done updating brew" && brew upgrade && echo "done upgrading brew"'
```

If you forget to quote this you could have something like

```
alias update sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade #...
```

where the alias is broken because it got three values instead of one, and the other commands aren't understood to be part of the alias at all - this would try to run `sudo apt upgrade` right after declaring the alias!

To be honest, I would always recommend you just make it a function (which is also what alias will end up doing) like so

```
function update
    sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && brew update && echo "done updating brew" && brew upgrade && echo "done upgrading brew"
end
```

That way you don't need to do any quoting and you get more control over where any arguments end up - here they're just dropped, with `alias` they would be given to the last command (`echo "done upgrading brew"`).

Comment: Thank You, I Just made a function for the whole thing.

Comment: For readability, I would replace all the `&&` with `[newline] and`